# Primitive Roots of a Prime P

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The question is:

Assume that *p* is an odd prime and that *g* is a primitive root for *p*. Also assume that

$$ g^{149} \equiv g^{-1} \pmod p.$$

Find all possible  choices of *p*.

---

I don't want the answer. I just can't even figure out the concept behind it.

Comment: Do you know the definition of all of the relevant terms?

Comment: **Hint:** What are all the possibilities that $p\mid g^n-1$ for some integer $n$? Notice what the definition of a primitive root modulo $p$ says.

Comment: __Hint:__ You want $149+1$ to be a multiple of some function of $p$.

Comment: My first thought was to re-write it as 

$$g^{150} \equiv 1 \pmod p$$. 

Then I could choose a prime, and I know that $g^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$. Suppose we choose $p = 7$. Then we can rewrite the equation as $(g^{6})^{25} \equiv 1 \pmod 7$. Thus 7 is a possible choice for $p$.

Comment: You are close to the solution yourself. Because $g$ is a primitive root (mod $p$), the multiplicative order of $g$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is exactly $p-1$. On the other hand, you have shown that $g^{150} =1.$

Answer (score 1):

A primitive root is one for which $p \mid g^n - m$ gives a different value of $m$ for each value of $n$ in $1<n<p-1$.  If $\operatorname{hcf}(p-1, q)=1$ then $g^q$ is also a primitive root.

It works out that $p-1 \mid 149+1$ in this example, giving $\frac{150}{p-1}$ periods of maximum length of $p$.  Evidently, it must divide $150$, otherwise the maximum period can not exist in that space.

So, one simply has to work through the divisors of $150$ (supposing the decimal hundred applies), and get a dozen numbers, of which many are one less than a prime.